# Add text field to cell in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uitextfield

I have a table view controller and I would like to add a hidden textfield to each cell. I drag my textfield onto the cell. I made `UITextField` class to control this textfield, and created an IBOutlet for it in this class. When I go to make my referencing outlet for the textfield, I cannot see the IBOutlet for the textfield I made.

How can I successfully add this textfield to my cell?

Comment: I made a UITextField class. This is wrong?

Comment: I want to long press the cell and then to be able to use the textfield to edit the cell's content. I have the long press gesture code, along with how to get the cell's contents. I just need to be able to send the content in the cell to the class that controls my tableview.

Comment: I am teaching myself how to develop apps. I am a beginner. I am used to setting referencing outlets to get data from the textfield. Am I going about this wrong?

Comment: A long press on the cell shows the textfield and brings focus to it allowing the user to interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend UITableViewCell and create your IBOutlet in it.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;

@end
```

Then, in your UITableViewController, instead of calling a generic UITableViewCell, you would do something like:

```
MyCustomCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
```